# jest typescript property mock does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking

When using `jest.fn()` to add a mock you can usually access the `.mock` property to access details such as calls, something similar to this:

```
test('not working', () => {
    const foo = new Foo();
    foo.addListener = jest.fn();
    foo.func(); // will call addListener with a callback
    const callback = foo.addListener.mock.calls[0][0];
    expect(callback()).toEqual(1); // test the callback
});
```

When implementing the test in typescript instead of plain javascript I get the error:

> error TS2339: Property 'mock' does not exist on type '(callback: () => number) => void'.

I can get rid of the error by casting to `any` but surely there must be a better way:

```
const callback = (foo.addListener as any).mock.calls[0][0];
```

In this simple code the mock could be rewritten to store the argument using `jest.fn(fn => { callback = fn; });` but the same error happens when using `foo.addListener.mockClear()` which cannot be reworked the same way.

So how can I get rid of the error, preferably without losing type-safety?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use [`jest.spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) in combination with functions like [`mockImplementation`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn) to mock a function while preserving type safety in TypeScript:

```ts
class Foo {
  addListener = (callback: () => number) => { }
  func = () => {
    this.addListener(() => 1);
  }
}

test('working', () => {
  const foo = new Foo();
  const mockAddListener = jest.spyOn(foo, 'addListener'); // spy on foo.addListener
  mockAddListener.mockImplementation(() => { }); // replace the implementation if desired
  foo.func(); // will call addListener with a callback
  const callback = mockAddListener.mock.calls[0][0];
  expect(callback()).toEqual(1); // SUCCESS
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to mock a function in the class without initiating it in the test?

Comment: The only catch to this approach is  you need to import the whole library as in `import * as _ from ''`, because the spy is applied to an object.

Answer (score 109):

For anyone getting here, a bit better than casting to `any` might be casting as jest.Mock

```
const callback = (foo.addListener as jest.Mock).mock.calls[0][0];
```

#### Update Sep 2021

To get a mocked function that both fulfills the mocked function type and the jest mock type `jest.MockedFunction` can be used:

```
const addListenerMock = addListener as jest.MockedFunction<typeof addListener>;
```

Answer (score 16):

Got the error below when using `axios`.

> TS2339 (TS) Property 'mockResolvedValueOnce' does not exist on type
> 'AxiosStatic'

Tried using `axios as jest.Mock` but got the error below:

> TS2352 (TS) Conversion of type 'AxiosStatic' to type 'Mock<any, any>'
> may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the
> other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown'
> first. Type 'AxiosStatic' is missing the following properties from
> type 'Mock<any, any>': getMockName, mock, mockClear, mockReset, and 12
> more.

Solved it by specifying as `axios as unknown as jest.Mock`

AxiosRequest.test.tsx

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { MediaByIdentifier } from '../api/mediaController';

jest.mock('axios', () => jest.fn());

test('Test AxiosRequest',async () => {
    const mRes = { status: 200, data: 'fake data' };
    (axios as unknown as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValueOnce(mRes);
    const mock = await MediaByIdentifier('Test');
    expect(mock).toEqual(mRes);
    expect(axios).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

mediaController.ts:

```
import { sendRequest } from './request'
import { AxiosPromise } from 'axios'
import { MediaDto } from './../model/typegen/mediaDto';

const path = '/api/media/'

export const MediaByIdentifier = (identifier: string): AxiosPromise<MediaDto> => {
    return sendRequest(path + 'MediaByIdentifier?identifier=' + identifier, 'get');
}
```

request.ts:

```
import axios, { AxiosPromise, AxiosRequestConfig, Method } from 'axios';

const getConfig = (url: string, method: Method, params?: any, data?: any) => {
     const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
         url: url,
         method: method,
         responseType: 'json',
         params: params,
         data: data,
         headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    }
    return config;
}

export const sendRequest = (url: string, method: Method, params?: any, data?: any): AxiosPromise<any> => {
    return axios(getConfig(url, method, params, data))
}
```

Comment: someone might do `axios.get()`

Answer (score 7):

`jest.spyOn` is the right way to go.

However, if you'd like to do the same with a simple function that's not a part of a class, you can use `jest.mocked`. Here's an example importing functions from Firebase:

```
/** Example code depending on a simple function */
import {
  addDoc,  // Function to be mocked
  collection,
  getFirestore
} from 'firebase/firestore';

export async function createRecord(record: any) {
  const collectionRef = collection(getFirestore(), 'example-path');

  return addDoc(collectionRef, record);
}
```

```
/** Unit tests for example code */
import { addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

jest.mock('firebase/firestore');

describe('Create record', () => {
  test('creates a new record', async () => {
    const mockedAddDoc = jest.mocked(addDoc);

    await createRecord({ hello: 'world' });

    expect(mockedAddDoc.mock.calls[0][0]).toMatchObject({ hello: 'world' });
  });
});
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockedtitem-t-deep--false

Comment: the `jest.mocked(dependency)` tip here is the key 

Comment: `jest.mocked(dependency)` worked for me!