# JestJS TypeScript: mockImplementation Does not Exist on Type

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Im learning Jest with TypeScript and I'm facing the following type error:

```
Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type '() => Element'.
```

Code:

```js
test("Should Render HomePage on Default Route", () => {
    // Arrange
    Home.mockImplementation(() => <div>HomePageMock</div>) // type error here

    // Act
    render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    // Assert
    const element = screen.getByText("HomePageMock");
    expect(element).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I have tried casting `any` but that doesn't seem to solve it:

```
Home.mockImplementation((): any => <div>HomePageMock</div>)
```

Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jest typescript property mock does not exist on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457575/jest-typescript-property-mock-does-not-exist-on-type)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can convince Typescript that this is a jest Mock object by using something like `const MockedTheClass = TheClass as jest.Mock<TheClass>`.

Example:

```js
import { TheClass } from "the-module";
jest.mock("the-module");
const MockedTheClass = TheClass as jest.Mock<TheClass>;

describe("something", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // No error here (except if your implementation does not match the spec of `TheClass`)
    MockedTheClass.mockImplementation(() => {
      // ... implementation
    });
  });

  // ... tests
});
```

Source: https://klzns.github.io/how-to-use-type-script-and-jest-mocks

Comment: Thanks for your help! Typescript didn't like ```<TheClass>``` but once removed then it seems to work with no type errors!

Comment: In my case I have to either leave out the type or use ```<JSX.Element>```