# Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, jestjs

The simple Jest 28.1 [mockImplementation example](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn) works but my VS Code still shows errors in the IDE as it is unable to identify some types:

```
// someclass.ts:

class SomeClass {
    method(a: string, b: string): void {}
}
```

```
// someclass.spec.ts:

import { SomeClass } from './someclass';

jest.mock('./SomeClass');

describe('someclass', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        SomeClass.mockImplementation(() => {
            return {
              method: jest.fn(() => {}),
            };
          });
    });

    afterAll(() => {
        SomeClass.mockReset();
    });

    it('should run method', () => {
        const some = new SomeClass();
        some.method('a', 'b');
    });    
});
```

When running Jest from command line or VS Code Jest Test explorer, it works, no errors. However, when hovering over the following respective functions in the IDE, I see these errors:

```
Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type 'typeof SomeClass'
Property 'mockReset' does not exist on type 'typeof SomeClass'
```

I didn't customize any Jest config, my package.json contains an empty `"jest":{}` section. How do I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jest typescript property mock does not exist on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457575/jest-typescript-property-mock-does-not-exist-on-type)

Comment: No, unfortunately. I ended up with a workaround of removing jest-ts transpiler and moving to babel